iTerm2 Triggers and file saving
I am trying to use a trigger in iTerm2 to take what is saved in the captured output to save that output to a file.
for instance -
captured output puts a log error in the panel, I want that result to be saved to a text file as well. does anyone know if this is even possible?
THanks
